# How to Stop AVPlayer and remove from superview after dismissing the viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, avplayer

I am trying to play video using AVPlayer in iphone video runs well but when i close that video controller in which my video is playing ,it crash my application ????please help how to close AVPLayer and remove from it's super view.

Answer (score 0):

If avPlayerLayer is the only class interacting with the avPlayer, you don't need to maintain a reference to it with a property in the class you're using to present it (unless this class uses it outside the code you've shared). In fact, this is probably why it isn't working the way you expect.

The reason the clip continues to play (I think) is because the player isn't being deallocated. You create it, own it with the strong property in your class, than it's owned again by the AVPlayerLayer class you hand it to. So when the AVPlayerLayer is deallocated, the AVPlayer looses one owner. But it still has an owner (your class), so it isn't deallocated, and it keeps playing. The solution here is to get rid of your owning property altogether for *avPlayer. You don't need it. Create the AVPlayer and pass it to AVPlayerLayer. That should be all that's needed.

Something else you could do which might fix the behavior but not the problem, call:

```
[avPlayer pause]
```

In your AVPlayerLayer's dealloc method.

Re: Strong vs. Weak references: A strong reference implies ownership. As ARC is managing memory, it'll be doing all the [object retain]ing and [object release]ing that you previously would have done in code OR that you would have done with properties, ie:

```
@property (retain) NSObject *iAmRetainedWhenProperyIsAssigned;
```

So now with ARC, we simple users don't use words like retain or release in code or when defining properties. But we still design software. ARC is smart, but not smart enough to infer the architectural implications of relationships that we're defining. It still needs to be told that a class "owns" a reference to the object that the property refers to. Which reduces us, in the most basic terms:

(strong) means to ARC what (retain) meant to properties pre-ARC (owned/retained)

(weak) means to ARC what (assign) meant to properites pre-ARC (not owned/not retained)

Answer (score 0):

My Last answer was understanding how that player object runs in memory as well free from there and before Xcode 5.1, we had used some methods which I had defined.

Now I will give you proper answer how to stop `AVPlayer` and remove from superview. Actually in `AVPlayer` stop method does not there instead you have to used paused which is delegate by `AVPlayer` object.

Just add this code:

```
[self.videoPlayer Pause];[self.avPlayerLayer removefromsuperlayer];self.videoPlayer = nil;
```

Comment: player is pause thats fine.player is remove that is also fine .But when i dissmiss my view controller it gives follwing errror. thanks in advance    reason: 'An instance 0x7f9e50d72dc0 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f9e50c94150> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f9e50d723e0: Observer: 0x7f9e50f9ffa0, Key path: status, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x102296318, Property: 0x7f9e50d5a350>

Comment: The solution was to remove the observer, before releasing the object.

When you replace or allocate a new object for a member, you're releasing the old object, so you need to remove the observer first [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the observer, before releasing the object. When you replace or allocate a new object for a member, you're releasing the old object, so you need to remove the observer first [player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"]; –  Nandan Deshmukh